# If checkbox is checked, then display message hello else display hi

Tags: php, woocommerce

I need your help. I want to rename the word "Free shipping" option on woocommerce when wholesale checkbox is checked with "Hello" and when it is unchecked I want to display "Hi". Below is the html I took from the site.

```
<td data-children-count="1">
        <input type="checkbox" name="wcs_wholesale_customer" id="wcs_wholesale_customer" value="1" checked="checked">Check this option to set this user to receive your wholesale pricing<br>
        <!-- <span class="description"></span> -->
</td>
```

and this is the function I added on functions.php

```
function sww_wc_free_shipping_label( $label ) {

  if(isset( $_POST['wcs_wholesale_customer']) && is_cart() && is_checkout() ) {
    $label = 'Hello';
   } else {
        $label = 'Hi';
    }

    return $label;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label', 'sww_wc_free_shipping_label', 10, 2 );
```

Please can you check what needs to be changed on these code above?

Comment: Do you want this to appear to the user the instant it is checked or not checked? Or did you want to store he value of the checkbox to display this message later on another screen?

Comment: @john yes, I want to display this message later too on another screen. But for now, my problem is that I dont know how to declare on php if statement when checkbox is checked or not.

Comment: Please take a look at my answer.

Comment: I am not sure if this is the right one if(isset( $_POST['wcs_wholesale_customer'])

Comment: Please see the 2nd half of my answer that I posted.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with HTML and CSS.  check out what I did here:

```css
.message {
   display: none;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .message {
   display: block;
}

.message2 {
   display: block;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .message2 {
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<td data-children-count="1">
        <input type="checkbox" name="wcs_wholesale_customer" id="wcs_wholesale_customer" value="1" checked="checked">Check this option to set this user to receive your wholesale pricing<br> <span class="message">hi</span> <span class="message2">hello</span> 
        <!-- <span class="description"></span> -->
</td>
```

As for doing it the PHP way, you can check if the checkbox was checked using code like this:

`<?php
if( empty($_POST["wcs_wholesale_customer"]) ) { echo "Checkbox was left unchecked."; }
else { echo "Checkbox was checked."; }
?>`

Comment: Thanks @john, it doesnt work. This checkbox is seen on user profile please see screenshot http://prntscr.com/sk3rxz do you think will need to get the value first from database? something like 
$a = get_user_meta('wcs_wholesale_customer') is this right?

Comment: Yes, you will need to grab the value from wherever this value is being stored then you will need to echo it in the correct place.

Comment: thanks @john, do you know how to get the field name of this checkbox in wordpress?

Comment: My guess it its probably "wcs_wholesale_customer" But I have no idea where it is stored in the db.  My guess is its in the user meta table.  Can you go in there and check?

Answer (score 0):

I finally sort out with the php code below:

```
function sww_wc_free_shipping_label( $label ) {
    global $current_user;
    $wholesale_customer = get_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'wcs_wholesale_customer', true );

   if( ( $wholesale_customer ) ) {

       if( WC()->cart->subtotal >= 80 ) {
        $label =  'WHOLESALE Shipping & GST to be added at dispatch';     
       } else {
           $label = 'WHOLESALE Shipping & GST to be added at dispatch + Flat rate of $10';
       }

   }

    return $label;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label', 'sww_wc_free_shipping_label', 10, 2 );
```

Thanks guys.